# Android not opening dropdown menu from select element

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I'm developing an mobile application using phonegap(2.9.0) and right now i'm struggling with few android bugs related to select elements.

In advance, sorry for the poor paint "wireframes" haha

[image]

There's a form inside the relative positioned container. The select elements were not opening the dropdown menu. After some research, this one was solved setting the meta tag viewport with "user-scalable = yes". Tested on Android 2.3.6: Samsung Galaxy Ace(GT-S5830C) and Motorola Defy Mini(XT-320); Android 4.1.2: Motorola Razr D3(XT920). However, it's not working on android 4.0.4: Samsung Galaxy S Duos(GT-S7562).

[image]

At this screen, there's a form inside the container inside the absolute positioned div. The select elements are not working even with the meta tag workaround. And this is driving me completely insane. At first, i thought that the problem was the fact that i'm styling the select elements. After removing EVERY style, it didn't work. The most close to a solution i've got was doing it programmatically with JS, however, despite the fact that only thinking about doing it make me want to cry, didn't work as expected, because the dropdown menus sometimes opened, sometimes not. Sincerely, i have no idea about why the hell is this happening. Tested on the same devices as the screen above.

Can anyone please help me??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

sorry this is so late, and this might not even help, but have you tried setting the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of the select element to something really high, like 1000 or so? It could be that you can see it but because it's so far back in the z-order it's just not selectable.